Starting point in MPC controller - y(i)
I wrote a MATLAB code for MPC for controlling room temperature. and set the setpoint on 25 degree, while the start point is 20 degree.
But in simulation the start point (20 degree) is deceased to zero and then is increased to 25 degree.
I think it should be increased until the room temperature reaches 25 degree.
I would like to know how should I write y(i) to increase the room temperature from starting point (20 C) to set point (25 C)?
For example each step will be increased 0.5C until reach the set point.
Do you know what's the problem?
clc;
clear;
% close all;
%%
T0 = 0;
Ts = 600;
Tf = 24 * 3600; % 24 hours in seconds
t = T0:Ts:Tf;
t = t';
system = tf([1 1],[1 1 2]); % Transfer function
h = step(system, t);
h = h(2:end);
StepInfo = stepinfo(system);
STime = StepInfo.SettlingTime;
N = floor(STime/Ts) + 1;
p = 5; % Prediction Horizon
m = 4; % Control Horizon
G = zeros(p, m);
for i = 1:m
    G(:, i) = [zeros(i-1, 1); h(1:p-i+1)];
end
H = zeros(p, N);
for i = 1:p
    for j = 1:N
        H(i, j) = h(i+j) - h(j);
    end
end
%% Discrete
system_dis = c2d(system, Ts);
B = system_dis.num;
B = cell2mat(B);
B = B(2:end);
A = system_dis.den;
A = cell2mat(A);
DegSys = numel(A) - 1;
%% Main Loop
Nt = numel(t);
y = zeros(Nt, 1);
u = zeros(Nt, 1);
dU = zeros(m, 1);
Umin = zeros(N, 1);
Q = 1;
R = 1;
Fval = zeros(Nt, 1);
W = 25 * ones(Nt, 1); % Setpoint of 25°C
dist = 0.1.*(t>6).*(t<=6.5) - 0.1.*(t>6.5).*(t<=7);
DIST = 0; % 1: add disturbance, 0: Don't Add
% Add noise to simulate temperature changes with a positive bias
% Ensure that noise increases gradually after the start point
noise = 0.5 * randn(size(t)) + 0.1 + 0.01 * (t / Tf); % Gaussian noise with a positive bias increasing over time
y(1) = 20; % Start point temperature of 20°C
for i = 3:Nt-1
    y(i) = -A(2:end)*y(i-1:-1:i-DegSys) + B * u(i-1:-1:i-DegSys) + DIST * dist(i) + noise(i);
    for j = 1:N
        if i-j < 2
            Umin(j,1) = 0;
        else
            Umin(j, 1) = u(i-j)-u(i-j-1);
        end
    end
    FreeResponse = H *Umin + y(i) + DIST * dist(i) + noise(i);
    Cost = @(Uplus) norm(W(i) - G*Uplus - FreeResponse , 1) + Uplus'*R*Uplus ;
    [Uplus ,Fval(i)] = fmincon(Cost , randn(m,1)) ;
    dU = Uplus ;
    u(i) = u(i-1) + dU(1);
end
%% Plot Results
figure(1);
subplot(2, 1 ,1);
plot(t(1:end-1)/(3600), y(1:end-1) , t(1:end-1)/(3600), W(1:Nt-1),  'LineWidth' , 2);
xlabel('Time (hour)');
ylabel('Temperature (°C)');
title('MPC Temperature Control');
legend('Output', 'Setpoint');
grid on

subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(t(1:end-1)/(3600), u(1:end-1) , 'LineWidth' , 1.5);
xlabel('Time (hour)');
ylabel('Control Input (U)');
legend('U');
title('Control Input (Effort Control)');
grid on

figure(2);
plot(t(1:end-1)/(3600), Fval(1:end-1) , 'LineWidth' , 1.5);
xlabel('Time (hour)');
ylabel('Cost Function');
legend('Cost Function');
title('Cost Function Variation');
grid on


The following plot shows after starting point (20 C), the room temperature goes to zero and then it goes up.

I guess y(i) is wrong and it should be modified.
